# What exactly has the National Ignition Facility recently achieved?

Tags: fusion

There's been some discussion recently (e.g. in [*Science*](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2021/08/explosive-new-result-laser-powered-fusion-effort-nears-ignition)) of an NIF yield of 1.35 MJ from a 1.9 MJ input. I *think* what this means is  they've set a record for empirical gain factor of $Q=0.71$. *Science* calls this

> close to “ignition”: a fusion shot producing an excess of energy.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusion_energy_gain_factor) would then be slightly out of date in saying:

> the record for $Q$ is... $0.67$... The highest record for extrapolated breakeven was... $1.25$... ITER was originally designed to reach ignition, but is currently designed to reach $Q = 10$

I've quoted more than the first number because there's a lot to unpack here:

- Nuclides such as tritium are too expensive to use in all experimental studies of their potential utility, so we tend to use something more plentiful to obtain empirical $Q$, then infer what $Q$ the same setup would achieve on the ultimately intended reactants. In this sense we have, but also haven't, achieved $Q>1$. (Less explicit sources sometimes don't address this subtlety.)
- The NIF's achievement will extrapolate to some $Q$ no source I've found estimates, but it will need to one day become quite high if we are to get excited. The same Wikipedia page notes $Q\ge5$ or so will allow the reaction to continue without external heating, and lead effectively to $Q=\infty$ in the long term, hence the term "ignition" (even if *Science* makes it sound like ignition only means $Q=1$). Also, the NIF might accomplish such objectives only after e.g. ITER does.

Sorry for that long preamble. My question is, what are the short- and long-term implications for $Q$ of the recent NIF achievement? Have they, for example, accounted energy in and out in a different way to Wikipedia (possibly due to their very specific approach to the energy injection timeline), so that what they've achieved is $70\%$ of the goal and not just $14\%$? Or is this really just a case of, "we took $24$ years to get from $Q=0.67$ to $Q=0.71$, so $Q=5$ is literally centuries away even if $Q$ grows exponentially?" (Or perhaps the intermediate, "we do need to increase $Q$ by $4.29$, but that could happen faster sooner than you'd expect once we get past a specific barrier"?)

I've had trouble finding *primary* literature on this event, so would appreciate being directed to examples thereof.

Comment: They achieved a burning plasma. That is the key point.

Comment: @JonCuster Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think all that means is $Q>0$ (not even for the first time with this technology, although the yield is far larger than in previous NIF experiments).

Comment: Better put, a self-propagating burning plasma.

Comment: @JonCuster From $Q=0.71$? Or are you suggesting the quoted yield is net, not gross, so really $Q=1.71$? Because *that* would be an exciting step towards $Q\approx5$.

Comment: The problem with focusing on Q is all the losses you need to account for. Getting a burning plasma to propagate is an important milestone. The fact that losses stopped it before Q exceeded 1 is irrelevant.

Comment: @JonCuster Cheers. I could ask another "so are you saying/so does that mean" question, but if you know of something I could read that explains NIF's recent achievement in more detail than the same two numbers of in/out MJ every journalist has copy-pasted, that would probably save us both writing more comments.

Comment: What they have achieved, IMO, is lots of publicity.  The fact these projects all require considerable funding means they need to make a big show of progress or the politicians run away to fund other things.  Most of these announcements are not for scientists (those in the field will hear about it on the gravevine), they're for governments and politicians.